# Currently remove a html-link from an image

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, hyperlink

situation:

- I have an image with a link around it.
- The link destination is generated by a PHP script.
- when the page loads, the link should be disabled. Later on, (when some forms are filled by user) the link should be enabled again.
- when the link is disable, I dont want any link behaviour (no mouse pointer change on hover etc. ...)

**Code**

```
    <a class="link" href="destination_generated_by_php_script">
        <img src="image_source_path">
    </a>
```

When I'm hiding the link, It'll hide the image as well (what i dont want). I thought about, to just display the image and wrap the anchor around it later on. But I guess, there's an easier answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like:

```
<a class="link" href="destination_generated_by_php_script">
    <img src="image_source_path">
</a>
```

and the jQuery script as:

```
var flag = false; //Global (Page Scope)
$('.link').click(function(e){
   if(flag){
     window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
   }else{
     e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Now when you want the click to work, just do:

```
flag = true;
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the `preventDefault();` function. But I didn't use a global variable. I've unbound the anchor of the "do-nothing-on-click-event" with `.unbind( "click" );`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by removing the `href` from the link. That way it won't appear as a link to the eye but CSS will still apply. If you do so, remember to save it somewhere so it can be properly restored.

```
var href;
href = $(".link").attr("href");

//remove href attribute and store it in data
$(".link").removeAttr("href").data("href", href);
```

When you want to activate the link again, you can do so like this

```
var href;
href = $(".link").data("href");
$(".link").attr("href", href);
```

The `data` can be removed as well (via `removeData()`) but is not necessary.

Comment: That's a nice answer, but I have several links on my site I desire that behaviour. Sorry, didn't mention that in my question.

Comment: @HansiZimmrer if you give different classes on links that shouldn't do this, or the same class to links that should. There should be no problem

Comment: @HansiZimmrer You can easily iterate over them via `.each()` if they share a class or something, no problemo ;)

Comment: Appreciate your help! Thanks, I'll experiment a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

use this function in you document accroding to your need.

```
event.preventDefault();
```

like you can use it as below

```
$('#link').click(function(event){
    if( form is not filled ){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
         //do nothing
    }
})
```